# Flutter upgrade to 3.19.3 lib/simple_cookies.dart No named parameter with the name 'primary'

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading to the latest version (3.19.3) of Flutter for my web application, I faced an error that was not present before the upgrade.

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/simple_cookies-0.1.0/lib/simple_cookies.dart:114:23: Error: No named parameter with the name
'primary'.
primary: Colors.green,

And I have latest version of simple_cookies: ^0.1.0

[Flutter Error: No named parameter with the name 'displayLarge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997381/flutter-error-no-named-parameter-with-the-name-displaylarge)

Based on above solution on Stack Overflow, I tried to remove the caret sign (^) in the google_fonts which included in pubspec.yaml file. And also included latest version of google_fonts which is google_fonts: 6.2.1. But, I am still facing the error.

Comment: That package was last published two years ago and therefore, might not be compliant with the latest version of Flutter. You have two choices: 1. find a different package 2. Alter the package source code

Answer (score 0):

I checked the package and the last update is two years old and in newer version of flutter `primary` field has been replaced with backgroudcolor color read about the [changes here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/3-16-deprecations#changes).

To fix this either remove the package and use a new one. or make changes in the package code and change it to the field.